# Enviar objetos para um template base.html Django

Tags: python, django

Minha situação é o seguinte, eu tenho um arquivo `base.html` onde mais de uma pagina da um `extend` nele. A minha dúvida é, como eu faço para enviar dois objetos para esse arquivo, para que esses objetos seja mostrado em todas as outras views, que der o extend nessa pagina(base.html);

Comment: Sua explicação está meio confusa, como poderia uma página dar um mais de um "extend" na template? Quando você diz "da um extend", você está querendo dizer que o controle dessa sua template está recebendo duas heranças de classes, é isso?

Comment: não, tipo, o base é uma masterpage, e as outras paginas, dão um extende nela

`{% extends "base.html" %}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> A minha dúvida é, como eu faço para enviar dois objetos para esse arquivo

Bem, para enviar dois objetos para um template você pode passar pelo `context` da função [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#render)

Ex:

```
def foo(request):
    object1 = Object1.object.all()
    object2 = Object2.object.all()

    context = {'object1': object1, 'object2': object2}

    return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

> para que esses objetos seja mostrado em todas as outras views, que der
>   o extend nessa pagina(base.html)

As variáveis/objetos que você envia para o template, ficam disponível apenas para o template que foi enviado.

Para que as variáveis/objetos fiquem disponíveis nos demais template será necessário usar [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#built-in-template-context-processors).

Ex:

views.py

```
def foo(request):
    object1 = Object1.object.all()
    object2 = Object2.object.all()

    context = {'object1': object1, 'object2': object2}

    return context
```

settings.py

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS += ("sua_app.views.foo", )
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu estava precisando. Vlw cara

Answer (score 4):

Você pode fazer dessa maneira na sua view:

```
{% extends variavel %}
```

E no projeto algo como isso:

```
import django.http
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
# declarando uma constante aqui
INDEX_EXTEND = "index.html"
# e utilizando algo como isso
def response(request) :
    return render_to_response("base.html", {'variavel': INDEX_EXTEND})
```

Leia mais aqui:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#extends